# The biblatex has problems with \par having \prevdepth

Tags: biblatex, paragraphs

Russian paragraphs have not too short last lines as the `\Arussian` substitution for `\par` does. But this approach creates conflicts with `biblatex` package. Is there any method to make it run?

Here is a short example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\let\origpar\par

% Donald Arseneau, [in:]
% Peter Wilson, Glisterings
% TUGboat, Volume 28 (2007), No. 2
\def\Arussianpar{\ifhmode \unskip
  \strut\vadjust{}\nobreak
  \discretionary{}%
    {\hbox{\hskip2\parindent
           \vrule depth 273sp
           width 0sp height \ht\strutbox}}%
    {\hbox{\hskip\parindent}}%
  \hskip-2\parindent minus 2\parindent
  \hskip\hsize minus\hsize
  \kern0pt\parfillskip0pt
  \origpar
  \ifdim\prevdepth=273sp
    \nobreak
    \vskip-2\baselineskip
    \hbox{\strut}%
  \fi
  \fi}

\let\par\Arussianpar

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

The `pdflatex` crashes with:

```
! Improper \prevdepth.
 \par ...arfillskip 0pt \origpar \ifdim \prevdepth 
                                                  =273sp \nobreak \vskip -2\...
```

Answer (score 3):

You get the errors when reading `english.lbx`, that is before starting to typeset the document.

You should be able to solve the issue by writing

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\par{\Arussianpar}}
```

instead of your

```
\let\par\Arussianpar
```

However there are many situations in LaTeX where `\par` is (locally) redefined, so you don't necessarily get the desired paragraph breaks in all cases.